# Regex: Non fixed-width look around assertions?

Tags: regex

My college asked my to provide him with a regex that only matches if the test-string endswith
`.rar` or `.part1.rar` or `part01.rar` or `part001.rar` (and so on).

Should match:

> foo.part1.rar
>   xyz.part01.rar
>   archive.rar
>   part3_is_the_best.rar

Should not match:

> foo.r61
>   bar.part03.rar
>   test.sfv

I immediately came up with the regex `\.(part0*1\.)?rar$`. [But this does match for `bar.part03.rar`](https://regex101.com/r/xG5mT4/3).

Next I tried to add a negative look behind assertion: `.*(?<!part\d*)\.(part\0*1\.)?rar$` That didn't work either, because look around assertions need to be fixed width.

Then I tried using a regex-conditional. But that didn't work either.

So my question: Can this even be solved by using pure regex?

An answer should either contain a link to regex101.com providing a working solution, or explain why it can't work by using pure regex.

Comment: **Everything** can be solved using regex.

Comment: Regex is like violence - if it doesn't solve your problems you are not using enough of it! (PCRE at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lookahead to verify the one case that fails your original regex (`.rar` with `.part` part that isn't `0*1`) is discredited:

```
^(?!.*\.part0*[^1]\.rar$).*\.(part0*1\.)?rar$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/mH5uF7/1)

Comment: Nice!! Lookaheads obviously don't need to be fixed width, only Lookbehinds.

Comment: to make it also **not** match on `foo.part19.rar` I had to change the regex to `^(?!.*\.part(\d*[^1]|[^0]*1)\.rar$).*\.(part0*1\.)?rar$`. (But that was not part of the initial testcase)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but here's another approach:

```
(?:\.part0*1\.rar|^(?<!\.)\w+\.rar)$
```

The idea is to match either:

- A string that ends with `.part0*1.rar` (ie foo.part01.rar, foo.part1.rar, bar.part001.rar), OR
- A string that ends with `.rar` and doesn't contain any other dots (`.`) before that.

Works on all your test cases, plus your extra `foo.part19.rar`.

https://regex101.com/r/EyHhmo/2